# IIS not allowing MVC application to control Error Messages on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Using the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159727/setting-http-status-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-results-does-not-render-view/3160526#3160526) I implemented the custom error handling logic. It worked well in my local PC running Visual Studio 2012, allowing me to create custom Views for 403, 404 and general errors. The problem is when I deployed it to Azure, IIS started to display the error messages, instead of my MVC application. Is there a configuration change I need to make to allow the MVC to control the error message handling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I'm not sure why the default settings are different for my PC (Windows 8 with IIS Express), but when deploying to Windows 2012 Server (IIS 8) you need to add the following in Web.config system.webServer section:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

Comment: I could kiss you! 
However, I'll doff my virtual cap to you sir, instead :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a different solution then the one you referenced.  I'm a little rusty on this, but I remember it being fairly simple to set up.  Not too much code or config.  Here's what my config looks like:

```
<!--This is the catch all error page.  All these views are located in project directory Views/Shared -->
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error/Error">
   <!--Custom 404-->
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/Notfound"></error>
  <!--Custom 401-->
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/error/NotAuthorized"></error>
</customErrors>
```

If you want to add custom/generic logging of errors try creating your own  [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  Use inheritance and override the OnException method.  Something like this:

```
public class CustomErrorHandler : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //your logging code here

        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

You can also catch exception and have them display custom error pages for you.  In my app I use it to customize my 401.  Here is what my Global.cs RegisterGlobalFilters looks like:

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CustomErrorHandler 
                        {
                            ExceptionType = typeof(NotAuthorizedHttpException),
                            View = "NotAuthorized",
                            Order = 2
                        });

        //Leave this line uncommented to let your customer error handler
        filters.Add(new CustomErrorHandler ()); 
    }
```

I didn't have to register any special route for this to work.  One last caveat.  Make sure that your error pages are included in your project otherwise they won't be deployed when you publish to Azure.

Hope that helps!

Comment: My goal is to create a log error before sending the user to the error page, that is why I liked using the Application_Error() event in Global.asax. There must be a config setting that I can use to allow the MVC app to control the error page opposed to Azure having IIS control it.

Comment: Updated answer to include recomendation on custom logging.

Comment: Interesting, but I believe this will still only handle errors in the scope of MVC. The Application_Error will handle any ASP.NET error. I've finally figure out the config value needed to make it work. I'll post it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the default error handler in the deployed version is overriding your Application_Error logic. Check the web.config transform that gets deployed and set to customErrors mode="On" and set the appropriate redirects. Then you need to disable the global filter HandleError.  Comment out the HandleErrorAttribute line in RegisterGlobalFilters.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Comment: I had commented out that section to get the custom error handling to work. I also have tried setting customErrors mode="On" and also tried "Off" and both produced the same result. The message returned from IIS on Azure is: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: I think you have conflicting error handling which is producing different results.  If you are doing error handling in Application_Error as described in your link, then remove the customErrors element.  Next make sure your controller/actions match the ones referenced in Application_Error. Finally, add Server.ClearError(); in Application_Error before Response.Clear();