# Cannot show custom error page on HTTP 403 in MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in the Global.asax.cs file in my MVC application which catches 500, and 404 errors and calls my ErrorsController which returns my custom error page depending on the code. This works fine. But this code is also supposed to catch 403 errors (unauthorized) so that my controller also displays the proper view for that too. But when I run it, I get an IIS page saying Unauthorized message. How do I get this code to call my ErrorsController, receive the 403 code, and display my custom view?

The way I tested it was that I placed an [Authorize] attribute on one of my actions and called that action. I should get the 403 error and my custom error page should be displayed.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Server.ClearError();

        RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Errors");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Feedback");
        routeData.Values.Add("exception", exception);

        if (exception.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode());
        }
        else
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", 500);
        }

        IController controller = new ErrorsController();
        controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815605/why-my-custom-404-error-handler-does-not-work-after-deployed-to-web-server/15816150#15816150

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Authorize attribute, you will not trigger an application error when authorization fails, it will just return a [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). This is why it is not working as you expected (and it should not work as you expected).

This stuff with custom error pages is a little bit messy in .Net MVC, but I suggest that you look at [HttpErrors](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors) or make your own custom [HttpModule](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996) that checks the status of outgoing responses and take appropriate action there instead.

Comment: (But I happen to know that there is an initiative for an neat open-source solution for this that is soon going to be published publicly, I'd keep my eyes open for that in the near future)